# update a MySQL table with Millions of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I need to convert ip by INET_ATON()
in mysql table have millions of rows

```
UPDATE `table` SET `ip` = INET_ATON(`ip`)
```

I need query to be fast and good performance

thank's

Comment: Is this a once off conversion or do you plan to do this in your project multiple times?

Comment: Why not store it in that format..

Comment: I agree with MichaelH that you should store the IP in INET_ATON() format. If that is not possible, you might modify your UPDATE so that it excludes the rows for which the IP is already in INET_ATON() format, perhaps using some date check or keeping a flag. That way the UPDATE will run on a smaller set and shouldn't have any performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems you're trying to assign a numeric value to a char column. As MichaelH said, if you're going to use the numeric value more than the address value, then you should consider storing the number in that format.

However, you can store both values to improve query performance:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  address char(15),
  number  int unsigned default 0
);

INSERT INTO t (address) VALUES
('255.255.255.255'),
('0.0.0.0'),
('1.0.0.0');

update t set number = inet_aton(address);
select * from t;
```

This would result in:

```
+-----------------+------------+
|     ADDRESS     |   NUMBER   |
+-----------------+------------+
| 255.255.255.255 | 4294967295 |
| 0.0.0.0         |          0 |
| 1.0.0.0         |   16777216 |
+-----------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use the [ip2long()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function in PHP when passing the IP address to the database?

And then when you want to return it, wrap the field in `long2ip`?